# How to handle generated key created by Firebase?

Tags: angularjs, json, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I need help while adding new record at that time one system generated key is created by Firebase (please check the below images) and I am having trouble while reading that JSON object. Please suggest me how should I read all node data.

[image: json with key]

or any alternative to access that system generated?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: please check image. in that you will see one object and i want to iterate that object to show in html but one auto generated key is their. so i have question how to deal with that auto generated key

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you use Ionicframework 1, forget about the key. You can read your JSON data by using `angular.forEach` method. For example:

```
.controller('youCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var firebase = {
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "xxxxxx.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxx"
    };

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
    ref.once("value")
        .then(function (snapshot) {
          var key = snapshot.key; // "-Kc6xMyVGkwcGStYU5f4"
          $scope.output_data = snapshot.val(); // Data to your view
        });
 })
```

---

In your view:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="data in output_data">
    <p>{{data.FirstName}}</p>
    <p>{{data.LastName}}</p>
    <p>{{data.Comments}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Hopes answered your question.